# Is it possible to change the validation of user names in sitecore10.1?

Tags: sitecore

In previous versions of Sitecore, username validation was defined with setteing name=AccountNameValidation.

In Sitecore 10.1, when I look at the results of ShowConfig, I don't see any definition of AccountNameValidation.

How can I redefine the username validation in Sitecore 10.1?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked the Sitecore.Kernel.dll in dotpeek.
The same setting is still available. It is just not shown in showconfig.aspx since it is not part of any config file.

Below is the code of Sitecore.Configuration.KnownSettings.CoreSettings class.

[image]

So if you want to override the default validation, you can put the same setting in Sitecore.config or create a patch config file.

```
<setting name="AccountNameValidation" value="^\w[\w\s]*$"/>
```

Good to read.
https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0259229